# angular directive to call scope method on click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a grid with button that has k-grid-cancel-changes class. I would like to create a directive that will attach a click event to that button and call method on the page scope

```
    .directive('kGridCancelChanges', function () { 
               return {
                restrict: 'C',                
                scope: {
                    onCancelChanges: "&"
                },
                controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
                    $element.click(function () {
                        $scope.onCancelChanges();
                    });
                }

            }
});
```

When I press button I can see $scope.onCancelChanges() fired from my directive but it never reaches function on the page scope.

```
 $scope.onCancelChanges = function () {
               alert('test');
            }
```

I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: did you try using `$apply`? Also try binding event inside `link` function

Comment: yes, I have tried: $scope.onCancelChanges(); $scope.$apply();

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I think you should do it in `link` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call a function in the scope it has to be provided like this:

```
<button class="k-grid-cancel-changes" on-cancel-changes="onCancelChanges()">test</button>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/8vQ1wmdriGrDFGZwhqW2?p=preview

If for some reason you can't modify HTML code (say, it's rendered dynamically by Kendo) and can't add attribute, then you can only access the function to call via `$parent` scope reference:

```
$scope.$parent.onCancelChanges();
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpEEZs9VQunKXABud9yN?p=preview

And finally, if it's not principal to have isolated scope for your directive then you can simply call the function as it's the same scope:

```
.directive('kGridCancelChanges', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
            $element.click(function() {
                $scope.onCancelChanges();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0OmlCJ6SgYU2GQRyBgYj?p=preview

Comment: Hi, $scope.$parent.onCancelChanges(); seems to be working, but I thought using $parent is a bad practise?

Comment: Yes, I would avoid using `$parent`. Just explaining to you your options. I would go with #1 or #3.

Comment: I have removed isolated scope and it is finally working. Thank you. Any reasons why I should  use isolated scope in this case ?

Comment: If you only need to create an event handler, then you don't need isolated scope. You would use it if you directive were to create some scope variables.

Comment: Great thx, what about controller vs link suggestions? does it make any difference in this case

Comment: Yes in your case you'd better use `link` function, this is where we bind event handlers to DOM normally.

Comment: I have tried to move it all into link, but it complains that 'oncancelchanges does not exist on value of type 'ng.lScope' - I am using typescript

Comment: Hm, not sure here. Double check everything, there should be no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can create you directive like this:

```
app.directive('myDir', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        scope: {
            foo: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope,elem){
            elem.on('click',function(){
               scope.foo(); 
            });
        }};

});
```

or use `controller` function instead of `link` if you need:

```
    controller: function($scope,$element){
        $element.on('click',function(){
           $scope.foo(); 
        });
    }};
```

Note that angular's `jqLite` has no `element.click` function.

Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cxo77xb4/2/

Comment: Thank you, for great example. I am sure I will use it in the future but in this case I can't modify html

Comment: @witpo you don't have to modify html. Just change the `foo` for the  `onCancelChanges`